# bash script contain perl code - and run on Python

Tags: python, bash, perl, shell, unix

I'm trying to run bash script - that contains perl code in it - on Python.
From some reason - it only execute the bash part and not the perl part.

The Python code that call's the bash Script is this : (2 options)

```
 bashCommand = "/bin/bash createUser.sh "+  str(self.emptyNameField.text()) +" "+ str(self.emptyPWField.text())+" " + str(self.emptyGroupField.text())
        os.system(bashCommand)

subprocess.call([path+'createUser.sh', str(self.emptyNameField.text()),str(self.emptyPWField.text()),str(self.emptyGroupField.text())])
```

And the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER_NAME="$1"
PASSWORD="$2"
UNIQUE_ID="$3"
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USER_NAME
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USER_NAME UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USER_NAME RealName "$USER_NAME"
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USER_NAME UniqueID $UNIQUE_ID
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USER_NAME PrimaryGroupID 1000
sudo dscl . create /Users/$USER_NAME NFSHomeDirectory /Local/Users/$USER_NAME
sudo dscl . passwd /Users/$USER_NAME $PASSWORD
export USER_NAME
export PASSWORD
export UNIQUE_ID


script=$(cat <<'EOF'

$file = "UsersList.txt";

open LIST, '>>',$file;
print LIST "$ENV{USER_NAME} @ $ENV{PASSWORD}\n";
close(LIST);
EOF
)
perl -e "$script"


echo "User Name: $USER_NAME , Password: $PASSWORD "
```

Any help would be much appreciated !!!

Comment: Did you try using the full path of the perl executable? like '/usr/bin/perl -e "$script"'

Comment: Rube Goldberg, is that you ?-) Seriously, why don't you add some generated C code and a call to gcc ?

Comment: I'm sure you could get some obfuscated code generators in there too!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can't say about collapsing your shell script into python, but all that `perl` does is:

```
echo ${USERNAME} \@ ${PASSWORD} >> UserList.txt
```

Seems a bit overkill to me.